# How to send data in jQuery datatable?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My script is this

```
function Search(){
    var Searchterm = $('#Searchterm').val();
   $("#grid-selection").DataTable({            //my table id 
        "ajax": {
            "url": "Premium/Home/Search",     
            "type": "GET",
            "data": Searchterm,              //need to send this value to controller
            "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columns" : [
                { "data": "id", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "title", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "title", "autoWidth": true }
                //{ "data": "Country", "autoWidth": true },
                //{ "data": "City", "autoWidth": true },
                //{ "data": "PostalCode", "autoWidth": true }
        ]
 });
    }
```

And my controller code is like this

```
public JsonResult Search(string Searchterm)
{
}
```

The value of `Searchterm` passed to the controller is `null`. What is the right way to pass the value to the controller?

Comment: `data: { searchterm: Searchterm }` and remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8` (and don't yell at us)

Comment: thanks a lot man upvoted. what does contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8 do anyways ?

Comment: `contentType` is the type of data sent to the view. In the case of `data: { searchterm: Searchterm }` its using the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`. If you wanted to use `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8` then you would also need to use `data: JSON.stringify({ searchterm: Searchterm })`

Answer (score 0):

Use function fnServerData here you have good example
[fnServerData](https://legacy.datatables.net/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html)

example for ajax

```
 $.ajax({
            'dataType': 'json',
            'type': 'POST',
            'url': sSource,
            'data': aoData,
            'success': function (data, status, dataOpt) {
            Your code

            }
        });
```

On .net I'm writing something like this:

```
 public DataTableResult PostDataTable(DataTableParams dataTableParam)
    { 
    }
```

DataTableParams  that class with parameters I need